# Dynamic Business Logic - Reflection internationalization

Tags: php, model-view-controller, localization, internationalization, business-logic

I am working on web application written in php Yii framework which needs to be internationalized/localized very soon. Currently My web application is using N(3) Tier Architecture (MVC). I have my business logic classes sitting in models and some component (general) classes. Now If I want to launch my platform into a new country/location where things can vary in my already built BL in component classes based on domain name/area. How should I architect this problem dynamically ?

For example

I have a case where I need validate a phone number for a country and I achieve this using one of my helper component method `Helper:validatePhone($phone)` but If I enter into new country

1. How should I differ or validate phone considering validation criteria would be different in new country and so on and so forth.
2. Should I load my business logic classes dynamically ?
3. What I want to avoid is no use of IF/ELSE should reside inside business logic layer e.g `if country = usa  {do this} else {do that}`

Comment: Please define what you mean by _"Should I load my business logic classes dynamically ?"_.

Comment: @dakis When I say load business logic dynamically I mean that my application should consume only required regional business logic class.
for instance if you are able to understand from following picture link ? 

https://ibb.co/C73VbgY